# Cannot update Image inside picturebox

Tags: c#, image, updates, picturebox, dispose

I'm making a small Reversi/Othello game and inside my method for drawing the board I have a nested for loop to display a grid of PictureBoxes each with an image in.

The first time the method is called all the PictureBoxes are created correctly and the images placed inside. However if I then call the method again I cannot seem to overwrite the images that are already there.

I've been researching for a while and as I understand it may be something to do with the PictureBox becoming locked or needing to correctly Dispose() the PictureBox before writing another image to it. I couldn't get any of these solutions to work though so any specific help would be much appreciated!

```
private void Draw()
{
    Bitmap White = Properties.Resources.white;
    Bitmap Black = Properties.Resources.black;
    Bitmap None = Properties.Resources.none;

    for (int r = 0; r <= grid.GetUpperBound(0); r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c <= grid.GetUpperBound(0); c++)
        {
            if (grid[r, c].value == 1)
            {
                var picbox = new PictureBox()                // initialise picturebox for displaying images
                {
                    Name = grid[r, c].name,
                    Size = new Size(64, 64),
                    Location = new Point(r * 65 + 15, c * 65 + 60),
                    Text = grid[r, c].name,
                    Image = White
                };

                Controls.Add(picbox);                // add picturebox to form 
                picbox.Click += ClickBox;
                MessageBox.Show("white draw" + grid[r, c].name);
            }

            if (grid[r, c].value == -1)
            {
                var picbox = new PictureBox()
                {
                    Name = grid[r, c].name,
                    Size = new Size(64, 64),
                    Location = new Point(r * 65 + 15, c * 65 + 60),
                    Text = grid[r, c].name,
                    Image = Black
                 };

                Controls.Add(picbox);
                picbox.Click += ClickBox;
                MessageBox.Show("black draw" + grid[r, c].name);
            }

            if (grid[r, c].value == 0)
            {
                var picbox = new PictureBox()
                {
                    Name = grid[r, c].name,
                    Size = new Size(64, 64),
                    Location = new Point(r * 65 + 15, c * 65 + 60),
                    Text = grid[r, c].name,
                    Image = None
                };

                Controls.Add(picbox);
                picbox.Click += ClickBox;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show how the whole method?

Comment: Sure! Edited to add the whole method.

Comment: And what is the `grid`?

Comment: @Valentin it's a 2d array that holds information about each piece on the board, like its Value.

Comment: Do you have only one picturebox? With the location equal to `Location = new Point(r * 65 + 15, c * 65 + 60)`

Comment: @Valentin it's an 8x8 grid of pictureboxes created by the method above. If there's a better way to go about it that will solve my problem then I'm happy to change it!

Comment: Where do you "update"?  I only see you adding new PictureBox controls.

Comment: It seems like you're completely recreating everything every time this method is called, which seems incorrect. You should create your PictureBoxes once only and add them to the Controls collection once only also. You should then only need to amend the properties of the controls, such as Image. If you're starting the game afresh, and calling this method, then ensure that the Controls collection has been cleared out and refilled correctly. You may not have to do this though, depending on your design. You may just be able to clear out the existing controls properties, ready for a fresh start.

Comment: @ManoDestra Thanks for the input. I did feel a bit weird creating the pictureboxes again every time. My new question would be that once I have created the pictureboxes once how to I go about referencing them later to change the properties? if i try and do picbox.Image it says the name does not exist in the current context

Comment: You need to store private class level references to the array of pictureboxes. They need to be accessible to the whole class.

Comment: If your PictureBoxes have unique names, then you can reference them with that name: `PictureBox pb = Controls["cellname"] as PictureBox;`

Comment: @ManoDestra Right! How do I go about storing references for the pictureboxes? I have given them names but that doesn't seem to be the same as a reference.

Comment: Put them at the top of your class definition e.g. `Private PictureBox[,] picBoxArray;` Then build that array once only. Then refer to it later via `picBoxArray[3, 4].Image = <code here for new image object>;` Something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you create new picturebox but do not remove/update the existing Picture box from `Controls`.
First of all you need to find a picture box you want to update or remove from `Controls`.

I suggest to create a grid of a Picture boxes, so you can get the picture box from the grid. First of all create the field.

```
private var pictureGrid = new PictureBox[8, 8];
```

And then

```
if (grid[r, c].value == 1)
{
    if (pictureGrid[r,c] != null) 
    {
        pictureGrid[r,c].Image = White;
    } 
    else 
    {
        var picbox = new PictureBox()                
        {
            Name = grid[r, c].name,
            Size = new Size(64, 64),
            Location = new Point(r * 65 + 15, c * 65 + 60),
            Text = grid[r, c].name,
            Image = White
        };

        pictureGrid[r,c] = picbox; 
        Controls.Add(picbox);                
        picbox.Click += ClickBox;
        MessageBox.Show("white draw" + grid[r, c].name);
    }
}
```

You also can use [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) that contains (grid.Value - Color) pairs.

```
private Dictionary<int, Bitmap> colors = new  Dictionary<int, Bitmap>();

private void Load() 
{
    Bitmap White = Properties.Resources.white;
    Bitmap Black = Properties.Resources.black;
    Bitmap None = Properties.Resources.none;

    colors.Add(1, White);
    colors.Add(-1, Black);
    colors.Add(0, None);
}
```

So your method will look like

```
private var pictureGrid = new PictureBox[8, 8];    
private Dictionary<int, Bitmap> colors = new  Dictionary<int, Bitmap>();

private void Load() 
{
    Bitmap White = Properties.Resources.white;
    Bitmap Black = Properties.Resources.black;
    Bitmap None = Properties.Resources.none;

    colors.Add(1, White);
    colors.Add(-1, Black);
    colors.Add(0, None);
}

private void Draw()
{
    for (int r = 0; r <= grid.GetUpperBound(0); r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c <= grid.GetUpperBound(0); c++)
        {
            if (pictureGrid[r, c] != null) 
            {
                pictureGrid[r,c].Image = colors[grid[r,c]];
            }

            else 
            {
                var picbox = new PictureBox()
                {
                    Name = grid[r, c].name,
                    Size = new Size(64, 64),
                    Location = new Point(r * 65 + 15, c * 65 + 60),
                    Text = grid[r, c].name,
                    Image = colors[grid[r,c]]
                 };

                pictureGrid[r,c] = picbox;
                Controls.Add(picbox);
                picbox.Click += ClickBox;
                MessageBox.Show("black draw" + grid[r, c].name);

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Also you can find the picture box to update using linq

```
var pictureToRemove = this.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>().Where(x => x.Location.X == r * 65 + 15 && x.Location.Y == c * 65 + 60).First();
```

Comment: Dispose, not Remove, unless you want to use it again in the future.

Comment: Ah I understand what you mean! This may be a noob question but how do I reference the pictureboxes i have created? if I simply use 'picbox' it says that the name doesn't exist in the current context. 

thanks for all your help btw!

Comment: @MBrazier4 I've updated the answer. I think solution with grid of picture boxes is most rational.

Comment: @Valentin Thanks so much! I think you're correct about making a grid of pictureboxes once and then referencing them from there. Going to try and implement this now.

Cheers for taking the time!

Comment: @MBrazier4 I've also added one hint with Dictionary, check this out :)

Comment: @Valentin All working perfectly so far! The Dictionary hint you gave is really elegant, cleans up the code a bunch! Thanks again bud